# Selenium IE Webdriver Proxy: Unable to locate hudsuckr.exe

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I cannot change the proxy settings of the IE Webdriver, because of following exception:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to locate: hudsuckr/hudsuckr.exe

Here's essentially what I am doing:

```
ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(1415);
server.start();
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
Proxy proxy;
proxy = server.seleniumProxy();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

The same code is working with the Chrome Webdriver, but I don't get it to work with IE. hudsuckr.exe seems to do some proxy configuration stuff for Windows, so I'm certain the problem lies there. I also already checked my virus scanner but it doesn't block hudsuckr.exe.
Is this a known issue with a solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by adding this to the code:

```
capabilities.setCapability("ie.setProxyByServer", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

hudsuckr.exe is included in the selenium-server-stanalone distribution package. Try adding this jar.